# How does `Control Sequence' work in terminal?

Tags: bash, terminal

GNU bash, version 4.1.10(4)-release (i686-pc-cygwin)

I tried`echo $'\e[33mtext'`, it displays yellow 'text'

I also tried to put several `sleep` between `echo`s, and it still worked.

Then I manually typed on the prompt 'ESC' '[' '3' '3' 'm', it displays a normal 'm' when I typed 'm', so these chars didn't lead a control sequence.

So what kind of chars can be interpreted as Control Sequence?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The control sequence has to be output to the terminal. Typing characters does not necessarily cause them to be echoed; in particular, typing <kbd>ESC</kbd> does not cause an escape to be echoed to the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Type

```
$ infocmp
```

and you'll see the list of sequences supported by your terminal.

```
$ man terminfo
```

will give you an idea of what the names mean.